# How to add PDF files as resources inside an executable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, jar

after many days of searching here and in google, and after many tries, i have finally decided to open an account for help.

Workspace environment: 
Latest Java version, Windows 8.1, Eclipse Luna

what i want to happen:
lunch my application from an executable jar, click a specific button and have a PDF file open.

up until now, i can do all that and it works... , except.

what actually happens:
my PDF folder is 20 MB and my jar file is 11 KB, and when i copy my jar file to desktop, lunch the jar file and click the button, no pdf file is opened.

my question is:

how can i integrate the files into the jar?

i have res folder for resources, i have heard of InputStream, FileReader, BufferReader, but cannot figure out how implement them in the code (i have tried, so many many times).
currently, i am using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + filePath);
```

in order to open the file right now, but it's not a permanent solution since there is no integration and no portability.

please, this is the final step for my application.
i cannot rest until it's finished.....

Comment: You need a PDF viewer that supports pdfs packed into jar files. Chances are that the system default viewers don't.

Comment: as i said, the exported jar works, but when i move it to a different location, say, desktop, it won't display the pdf files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have realized that  all i needed to do for portability was to bundle the jar file and resource file in the same folder, and that was it.
in fact, having the resource file accessible was far better than having it in the jar (keeping the jar now at only 13 KB), thus, allowing me to edit the resource folder as i see fit is way more flexible.

thank you all for your patient and the willing to help.

this question can be closed now.

Comment: *this question can be closed now* - You are the one who can close it by accepting an answer, e.g. yours. Probably one has to wait some hours before one can accept one's own answer.

Answer (score 0):

try on commandline something like:

```
Jar uf [your jar] res/afile.pdf
```

Comment: sorry, did not work.
plus, the files needs to be integrated into the jar, the whole problem is, they are not.

i have an entire class to find out the path of the needed pdf file (since there are many files in many folders)

Comment: You want to integrate? Then create a folder e.g. res in to your project in eclipse and get the assets in your code. Test in eclipse. Then when it works export to your jar.

Comment: And eliminate the complicated folder structure. If you integrate, the folderstructure is irrelevant and needlessly complicating.

Comment: i have res folder for resources, all the assets are there and everything works when i run it in eclipse, i can even export it and the jar works, problem begins when i move the jar file to desktop, another computer etc.
i am missing that line of code that will read the file into the jar, much like can be done with pictures.
i simply cannot figure it out.

Comment: a resource folder that contains 3 folders, an answers folder, FAQ folder and questions folder. 
each one contain a number of pdf files in the format of q<questionNumber>.pdf and a<answerNumber>.pdf
the FAQ contain a single pdf file called FAQ.pdf
the asset-get code is 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + filePath);
there are 2 classes, each of them handles the path to the right right.

this is basically a test simulator with answers.

Comment: the relative path string:
<br/>
String relativePath = "\\java\\NumberRandomizer\\res\\";
<br/>
the full path is calculated and then get send to this code:
<br/>
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + filePath);

Comment: Where to start. First you are using a relativepath which explains why moving your jar to the desktop makes opening the relative, not absolute path. Second you are not referring in your code to your assets uploaded in your project. So please first try and upload one of your pdfs as a testfile and address this file directly., i.e. Not using a relative path and not using the folder structure

Comment: And if you cannot succeed, think about creating a new table in your db and upload all pdfs as blobs or clobs in this new table.

Comment: addressing the file directly did help with portability, but of course, when i tried the jar on a different computer, it was a no go.
i have a class that identifies the file needed to be open from a random number:<br>

String filePath = this.relativePath + "questions\\" + this.testNumber + "\\q" + questionNumber  + ".pdf";
<br>
then the string is sent to it's parent class to be opened.